# Largest triangle in the unit circle

Tags: calculus

I need to maximize the area of a triangle which is laying in the unit circle and its area described by $f(x,y)=0.5 \cdot (sin(y-x)-sin(y)+sin(x))$ for $0\le x\le y \le 2\pi$

I calculated the gradient of $f(x,y)$ and it came out that it is equal to zero if and only if $cos(x)-cos(y)=0$. This is when $x=2k\pi +y$ and $x=2k\pi - y$ for integer k.

But now I'm stuck, how to go on? I saw on other pages that the solution is something with $2\pi /3$ but I don't see it here.

Can someone help me? :)

Comment: 2 dimensions...

Comment: No its the area of the triangle.

Comment: basically I just need to know how the user marwalix could conclude the solution 2pi/3 at the end https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298379/finding-the-largest-triangle-inscribed-in-the-unit-circle

Comment: No one can help? :(